# How did I split a string using re module with '()' as a delimiter?

Tags: python, string

I have some lines stored in a txt file like this.

*A    () Definition of A*

*Aardvark    (n.)   Definition of Aardvark*

These definition are just placeholder for now since the actual definition are long.
So I want to split these strings with ("any word here") as a delimiter. But my code doesn't seem to work.

```
import re

f1=open("A-shortened.txt","r")
l=f1.readlines()
#print l


for i in l:
    list=re.split("\(()')",i)
    print list
```

the part inside re.split is confusing me a lot. I've tried many arguments but none seem to split the string as I want.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't worry, however confused you might be -- we're even MORE confused. Are you trying to split on the part of speech? So `"Term (part of speech) definition" -> ["Term", "definition"]`?

Comment: Can you give an example of the result? E.g. when splitting `'Aardvark (n.) Definition of Aardvark'` do you want `['Aardvark', 'Definition of Aardvark']` returned?

Comment: Yes, I want to the output as ['Aardvark', 'Definition of Aardvark']. Sorry for not mentioning it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delimiter must match the parts of the string that you want to be removed *in between*. It's a little tricky because `(` and `)` are the group chars, but here you go:

```
text = 'Aardvark (n.) Definition of Aardvark'
re.split(r'\s*\([^)]*\)\s*', text)
```

`r''` prevents any accidental backslash escapes. It does not matter here, but better safe than sorry.

`\(`  and `\)` match literal `(` and `)`.

`[^)]` matches anything but right brackets. Note: no backslash escape here.

`\s*` makes any spaces before and after the brackets part of the delimiter, so that your split parts do not start with spaces. Simplify to `r'\([^)]*\)'` if you want those spaces.

Comment: the `re.X` flag is really good for explaining regular expressions like these, since it ignores leading and trailing whitespace on a line and respects comments unless escaped. See my nearly identical answer :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Unfortunately it is all to easy to miss the `re.X` in your formatting ;-)

Comment: thanks for this. it still confuses me as to how this works though. Even in the python doc explaination its confusing since there so many ways to go about it.

Comment: @frozenchaze Can you pinpoint what is still confusing you? Is it the concept of the regular expression itself or how `split()` is dealing with the regex fed to it?

Comment: basically my teacher didn't elaborate on this topic with much examples and kinda just went over it. it's partly my laziness though.I understood the topic but the pattern that has been fed into the split() is confusing but not impossible to understand I think. I'll go over it again but thanks for your help. cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex to something like this:

```
>>> s = 'Aardvark (n.) Definition of Aardvark'
>>> re.split(r'\s*\(.*?\)\s*', s)
['Aardvark', 'Definition of Aardvark']
```

`'\s*\(.*?\)\s*'` basically means: match all possible spaces followed by anything around `(` and `)` along with all the possible spaces after that.

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to split by an open paren, any number of non-close paren characters, and a close paren. So your regex should look like:

```
split_by = re.compile(r"""
    \(                   # literal open paren
    [^)]*?               # anything but a close paren, repeated 0+ times (non-greedy)
    \)                   # literal close paren""", re.X)

s = "Aardvark (n.) Definition of Aardvark"
split_by.split(s)  # ["Aardvark ", " Definition of Aardvark"]
```

If you'd like to grab those spaces too:

```
re.split(r"\s*\([^)]*?\)\s*", s)
```